# What is the number next to the post on which I've raised a flag?

Tags: support, flagging, design

I have recently noticed that there's a small number next to the post on which I have raised a flag. Here's a picture of what I mean: [image]
The number on the left is the score of the question. My question is what is the number on the right?

Comment: It is the number of answers.

Comment: Oh okay thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The number on the right is the number of answers the question has.